# Calculation - Direction values from rotation angles

Tags: python, geometry, cad

Not sure if I should be asking here or Maths section of Stackexchange.

I have a vector of 3 rotation angles ( ie. about x,y,z axis)
and wish to create the direction vector that an object would need if the
3 rotation angles were applied i.e. dir(a,b,c)

I would like to use PythonOCC so my creation of an object looks like

```
BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(gp_Ax2(gp_Pnt(0,0,0), gp_Dir(0, 0, 1)), \
                          10,10,10).Shape()
```

So it is the correct values for gp_Dir() I would like to calculate if
the object was to be rotated by the vector of 3 rotation angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may apply multiple rotation angles incrementally (see `gp_Trsf::SetRotation(gp_Ax1 theAxis, Standard_Real theAngle)` taking axis and angle) or use the following tools in Open CASCADE Technology:

1. Define cumulative **rotation** in form of **gp_Quaternion** class. Beware, that rotation angles applied in different order will result in different final transformation - that's why there is an enumeration **gp_EulerSequence**. Literature in various domains has different choice of preferred sequence.
2. Construct a **transformation** **gp_Trsf** from gp_Quaternion. gp_Trsf may define not just a rotation, but also a uniform scaling and translation vector.
3. Apply transformation gp_Trsf onto **gp_Ax2**.
4. Construct your object via **BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox** or another shape building tool.

```
    gp_Quaternion aRotQ;
    aRotQ.SetEulerAngles (gp_EulerAngles, 0.1 * M_PI, M_PI, 0.5 * M_PI);
    gp_Trsf aTrsf;
    aTrsf.SetRotation (aRotQ);
    gp_Ax2 anAx2 (gp_Pnt(0, 0, 0), gp_Dir(0, 0, 1));
    anAx2.Transform (aTrsf);
    TopoDS_Shape aBox = BRepPrimAPI_MakeBox(anAx2, 10, 10, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try, might be a few days though. Assuming it checks out I will give it the tick etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply all [matrices of rotation around axes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations) in needed order (note that order is important).

```
ResultingRotMtrx = RotX * RotY * RotZ
```

Then multiply initial direction (`(0,0,1)` in your case) vector by this `ResultingRotMtrx` to get final direction.

Comment: Sorry don't understand, I don't have any rotation matrix. I have a vector of three rotation angles, i.e. angle object makes with x,y,z axis.

And I am trying to calc what the gp_Dir(Vector) should be

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "vector of three rotation angles"? I added link.